# twisted python logging issue / confusion?

Tags: python, logging, twisted

I have an SMTP server based around http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/_downloads/emailserver.tac

This incorporates "custom_esmtp.py", which contains overloaded versions of some of the classes found in twisted's smtp.py - which is itself included to allow for classes for which there is no overloaded version.

By default, there is no log.startLogging line in any of the above 3 mentioned files. However, I do get some basic log output to stdout:

```
> # twistd -ny mailserver.tac
2014-10-29 15:35:53+0000 [-] Log opened.
2014-10-29 15:35:53+0000 [-] twistd 14.0.0 (/usr/bin/python 2.6.6) starting up.
2014-10-29 15:35:53+0000 [-] reactor class: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor.
2014-10-29 15:35:53+0000 [-] ConsoleSMTPFactory starting on 25
2014-10-29 15:35:53+0000 [-] Starting factory <__builtin__.ConsoleSMTPFactory instance at 0x31d67a0>
2014-10-29 15:35:55+0000 [mySMTP,0,127.0.0.1] Receiving myESMTP message for delivery: from=user1@nonpurdomain1.mta.test to=['user1@prefix-subject.domain.reg.test']
```

I assume this is some sort of standard level twisted logging - but open to being corrected.

However, if I add:

```
> log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
```

To the main method of emailserver.tac (with the required import statement of course) - then I get a flood of thousands of log entries which seem to be just the date/time stamp of an empty log line:

```
[-] 2014-10-29 15:15:20+0000 [-] 2014-10-29 15:15:20+0000 [-] 2014-10-29 15:15:20+0000 [-] 2014-10-29 15:15:20+0000 [-] 2014-10-29 15:15:20+0000 [-] 2014-10-29 15:15:20+0000 [-] 2014-10-29 15:15:20+0000 [-] 2014-10-29 15:15:20+0000 [-] 2014-10-29 15:15:20+0000 [-] 2014-10-29 15:15:20+0000
```

Can anyone offer a reason why / what is happening? What is the significance of the [-] - I assume when there is no connected client... but when there is, where does this become the 3 values shown - and what is the 2nd value??

Kinda lost here, and looking to understand how this logging is working, so I can tweak it to meet our requirements.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
log.discardLogs()
log.startLogging(sys.stdout)
```

First thing is that twistd runner calls log.startLogging(...) in its internals. 
Second thing is that every time log.startLogging(...) is called it writes initial message to opened log stream.

Because of u'r running twistd in debug mode (-n) twistd makes the exact call that you do log.startLogging(sys.stdout). So when the log.startLogging(...) is called twice, second call tries to write initial message that is also written by a first logger and the effect that you have seen happens.

However, you don't actually need to call log.startLogging(...), you should use one of the twistd options:

```
-l, --logfile=   log to a specified file, - for stdout
--logger=        A fully-qualified name to a log observer factory to use
                   for the initial log observer. Takes precedence over
                   --logfile and --syslog (when available).
```

Also you have no chances to remove first three strings from your log, while you are using twistd.

```
2014-10-29 15:35:53+0000 [-] Log opened.
2014-10-29 15:35:53+0000 [-] twistd 14.0.0 (/usr/bin/python 2.6.6) starting up.
2014-10-29 15:35:53+0000 [-] reactor class: twisted.internet.epollreactor.EPollReactor.
```

But the factory output can be muted by setting protocol noisy attribute:

```
ConsoleSMTPFactory.protocol.noisy = False
```

I hope it will help and give you some understanding of twisted logging.